# Convex conjugate of the exponential, via subdifferentials

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, exponential-function, legendre-transformation

Can anyone explain how to go about finding the convex conjugate of $\mathbb{R}\ni x \mapsto e^x$ via the subdifferential convex analysis tricks?

Comment: What do you mean by "subdifferential convex analysis trick"?

Comment: @gerw is there not an easy way to compute convex conjugates via the subdifferential and the subdifferential of the conjugate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is differentiable, then it is true that $f^*(f'(y))= yf'(y)-f(y)$.

Now let $f=\exp$. Then $f'=\exp$ as well and thus
$$ f^*(\exp(y))=y\exp(y)-\exp(y).$$
Writing $y=\ln(x) \Leftrightarrow \exp(y)=x$ gives
$$f^*(x)=x\ln(x)-x \quad\text{for $x>0$.}$$
Taking $x\to 0^+$ gives $f^*(0)=0\ln(0)-0 = 0$.

It is known from Convex Analysis that the range of $f'$ is dense in the domain of $f^*$. (This result is nontrivial.) Thus the domain of $f^*$ equals $[0,+\infty[$.

We record altogether

$$f^*(x) = \begin{cases}
+\infty, &\text{if $x<0$;}\\
0, &\text{if $x=0$;}\\
x\ln(x)-x, &\text{if $x>0$.}
\end{cases}$$